# How do I allow a button to have two separate behaviours depending on its classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Within a bootstrap modal I have a button, this button's properties change depending on some data so that the button may have one of two states.

State1

```
<button type="button" class="btn action-complete-task">Action 1</button>
```

State 2

```
<button type="button" class="btn action-complete-task action-2">Action 2</button>
```

Depending on the state of this button, I want it to execute the corresponding javascript function on click, either `action1()` or `action2`.

I have attempted to use CSS selectors to enable this, however the code I have below does not work. I read that by combining two classes in a JQuery selector without spaces such as `.class1.class2`, the selector will perform a logical AND and will only select elements that contain both `class1` and `class2`.

In my below code I have `$("#EditTask .action-complete-task.action2")`, which should select only the elements which have both classes `.action-complete-task` and `.action-2`, however in this particular scenario only the `action1()` function is executed.

```
//Action1()
$(".action-complete-task").on("click", function (event) { //do action 1 }

//Action2()
$(".action-complete-task.action-2").on("click", function (event) { //do action 2 }
```

The reason I want to use classes to determine the behaviour and not specific IDs is due to there being other functions that affect the design of the button using the class selector `.action-complete-task`, therefore I want the design of the button to be effected regardless of which state the button is in.

Comment: The listeners you set up are added at the time that line is executed. Which means if the button doesn't have the `action-2` class when that jQuery code runs, the 2nd line ends up doing nothing. What you need to do instead is add a single listener, and inside, check `$(this).hasClass("action-2")` (also note that even if it did work your way, clicking the button in state 2 would fire both functions, so even switching to `$(document).on("click", ".action-complete-task", ...)` wouldn't work)

Comment: `$(".action-complete-task").not(".action-2").on("click"` ... and you should add the code that changes the states

Comment: @johnSmith Like I explained in my previous comment, the class test has to be performed at the time of the click, not when the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do.

```
$(".action-complete-task").on('click', function(event){
  if($(this).hasClass('action-2')){
    //Do action 2
  }else{
    //Do action 1
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solution for this such as:
1. Add `action-1` class to your first button, so that the handler would be

```
$(".action-complete-task.action-1").on("click", function (event) {})
```

2. Make it one single handler but provides function that checks the class inside

```
$(".action-complete-task").on("click", function(e) {
  const buttonClass = e.target.attr('class')
  if (class.includes('action-2') {
    // handle action 2
  } else {
    // handle action 1
  }
})
```

Comment: Like I explained in my comment, method (1) will not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Pure JavaScript**

Check if the clicked element contains 'action-2' class.

```js
performAction = (e) => {
  if (e.className.indexOf('action-2') === -1){
    console.log('Perform Action 1')
  }
  else {
    console.log('Perform Action 2')  
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn action-complete-task" onclick="performAction(this)">Action 1</button>
<button type="button" class="btn action-complete-task action-2" onclick="performAction(this)">Action 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand your problem you could bind the event to a parent element that exists on pageload fore example `document`

```
$(document).on('click','.action-complete-task:not(.action-2)',function(){
//...1
})

$(document).on('click','.action-complete-task.action-2',function(){
//...2
})
```

this way it should work with manual inserted elements (DOM-Manipulation) and not fire the action1 (as it does now because your .action-2 also belong to .action-complete-task)

Comment: I prefer to use `$(body).on('click','.action-complete-task.action-2',function(){
//...2
})`, but I think there is no big difference, I only comment to let other know that there is this option too.